# What does "I got me a woman" mean?

Tags: verbs, lyrics

I am trying to understand some lyrics:

> I got me a woman, she's so good to me 
> I got me a woman, she's the girl
>   of my dreams

and so on

I would have written "I got a woman". I know "got me" only by adding a verb, like "I got me doing something".
 What difference does that "me" means in relation to "got"? Is it something colloquial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "I obtained [for me] a woman."

" Got me a(n) {X}" is indeed idiomatic in some dialects of American English. In particular, that of Southern black people from whom "the blues" originated.   It would not be considered proper in "standard" written English, but it is quite understandable (by a native speaker) as a song lyric. So, yes, it is colloquial.